# Stop a machine learning training but keep current state of the model with Vowpal Wabbit

Tags: machine-learning, vowpalwabbit

I am currently running a training phase using vowpal wabbit. The data set is big (4GBytes), and it has already run a whole night long. It is still training, and I don't know how many days it could last.

Do you know if there's a way to stop the training, but keep and save the model in its current state, so has to test it on real data ?

Comment: Just for clarification, you don't have access to VW output on `stderr`? It's usually pretty helpful to see how your model is performing (the `average loss` field is a validation error) and to see how fast it runs.

Comment: Yes, I do have access to stdout it seems. The average loss was asymptotically stuck to something like 0.31.  So I killed the training knowing I can now get this result in a few hours. But as the answers said, I have to consider the fact that indeed my training is slow, so I much change something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you knew that in advance you could use either `--save_per_pass` (so a model is save after every pass), or if you do just one-pass learning, you can include special examples with [tag](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Input-format) `save_filename` where filename is the path where the model should be saved.

If you do multi-pass learning and the first pass ended (so a cache file was created), you have no way to to include the `save` example in the training data, so I am afraid you have no easy way to save the model trained so far.

I would say 4 GiB is a small dataset:-). When I trained on 10GiB (compressed) dataset (which is also not big), it took two hours (including creation of the cache file, which takes most of the time, further passes/experiments are much faster), without any parallelization. Of course, it depends on the dataset, online vs. batch learning, the reductions and parameters used and especially the number of passes and hard drive speed, but "whole night" seems to me too long for such a small dataset.

As @user3914041 said, check the stderr log.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to stop VW at any point of time and dump its model state. If you train from file you may try to estimate current VW progress and delete piece of data so VW could just reach the end of dataset. You should keep in mind that VW uses buffered reading.

Or, perhaps better approach, is to insert `save` example into training dataset. If you launched VW with `-f` param then you'll see specified model file created once VW reaches this example. When you don't specify `-f`, but you have `save_foo|` example in your dataset, the model will be saved into file called "foo". Then you can kill VW process.

All these suggestions are dirty hacks that may or may not work. You better plan beforehand when you want your model to be saved and use one of options proposed by Martin next time.

UPDATE: Included Martin's note.

Comment: When you don't specify `-f`, but you have `save_foo|` example in your dataset, the model will be saved into file called "foo".